# org.osgi.service.event.Event.validateTopicName restricted certain characters

Tags: java, eclipse

I am kind of newbie to Java and I am facing an issue while firing an event. I have a method to fire(create) an event which is calling the eclipse function org.osgi.service.event.Event.Event(String topic, Map properties)

Now this method is calling a function private static void validateTopicName(String topic) to validate provided topic name. 
Actually I am using some symbol in name so those are getting pass to the topic parameter(for example "["). 
In validateTopicName there is a validation for topic for certain characters only (`i.e. "A-Z,a-z,0-9,-,_`") so it's throwing error of java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.
I want to know why there is a limitation of certain characters in above method? And how can I overcome of this issue?

`

```
private static void validateTopicName(String topic) {
        char[] chars = topic.toCharArray();
        int length = chars.length;
        if (length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty topic");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char ch = chars[i];
            if (ch == '/') {
                // Can't start or end with a '/' but anywhere else is okay
                if (i == 0 || (i == length - 1)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid topic: "
                            + topic);
                }
                // Can't have "//" as that implies empty token
                if (chars[i - 1] == '/') {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid topic: "
                            + topic);
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (('A' <= ch) && (ch <= 'Z')) {
                continue;
            }
            if (('a' <= ch) && (ch <= 'z')) {
                continue;
            }
            if (('0' <= ch) && (ch <= '9')) {
                continue;
            }
            if ((ch == '_') || (ch == '-')) {
                continue;
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid topic: " + topic);
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of the Event topic is defined in the OSGi specifications (section 113.3.1 of the OSGi Compendium):

```
topic ::= token ( '/' token ) * 

token ::= ( alphanum | '_' | '-' )+

alphanum ::= ::= alpha | digit

digit ::= [0..9]

alpha ::= [a..zA..Z]
```

You will have to convert your topics to conform to this.

Comment: Thanks Greg,
But I can't convert my topics by removing the characters as it can cause the issue while reading the listener.

Comment: @Jaydeep if you want to use these events you have no choice. You cannot subvert this specification.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a valid topic and put your invalid topic in the properties argument.